# Detecting if an Internet Explorer process is running Flash Player

Tags: c#, flash, internet-explorer, winapi, process

Ok, here is a little 1 million dollars question. I'm developing an application that checks if any of your browsers is currently running a Flash application. Here is my core native implementation:

```
// Using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot allows to list all the modules loaded by a specific process.
internal static Boolean ProcessContainsModule(Process process, String moduleMask)
{
    IntPtr snapshotHandle;

    if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        snapshotHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot((SnapshotFlags.Module | SnapshotFlags.Module32), (UInt32)process.Id);
    else
        snapshotHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Module, (UInt32)process.Id);

    if (snapshotHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return false;

    Boolean result = false;

    ModuleEntry entry = new ModuleEntry();
    entry.Size = ModuleEntry.SizeOf;

    if (Module32First(snapshotHandle, ref entry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (entry.ModuleName.FitsMask(moduleMask))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }

            entry = new ModuleEntry();
            entry.Size = ModuleEntry.SizeOf;
        }
        while (Module32Next(snapshotHandle, ref entry));
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshotHandle);

    return result;
}

// This is a simple wildcard matching implementation.
public static Boolean FitsMask(this String value, String mask)
{
    Regex regex;

    if (!s_MaskRegexes.TryGetValue(mask, out regex))
        s_MaskRegexes[mask] = regex = new Regex(String.Concat('^', Regex.Escape(mask.Replace(".", "__DOT__").Replace("*", "__STAR__").Replace("?", "__QM__")).Replace("__DOT__", "[.]").Replace("__STAR__", ".*").Replace("__QM__", "."), '$'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return regex.IsMatch(value);
}
```

Now, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) was very useful during my processes exploration.

Detecting this with Chrome is very simple:

```
if ((process.ProcessName == "chrome") && NativeMethods.ProcessContainsModule(process, "PepFlashPlayer.dll"))
```

Detecthing this with Firefox is also very simple:

```
if ((process.ProcessName.StartsWith("FlashPlayerPlugin")) && NativeMethods.ProcessContainsModule(process, "NPSWF32*"))
```

Like always, everything changes when you are looking at Internet Explorer. Any clue about how to detect this with Microsoft's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it:

```
if ((process.ProcessName == "iexplore") && NativeMethods.ProcessContainsModule(process, "Flash32*"))
```

Comment: Dude, the code for ProcessContainsModule is just on the first post.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake.  Interesting choice for a namespace name then

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code by Zarathos to make it actually compilable, as well as add some personal touches.

**tl;dr:** This works for Firefox, sometimes for Chrome, not at all for IE

First off, here's the basic code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

#region pinvoke.net boilerplate

[Flags]
private enum SnapshotFlags : uint
{
    HeapList = 0x00000001,
    Process = 0x00000002,
    Thread = 0x00000004,
    Module = 0x00000008,
    Module32 = 0x00000010,
    Inherit = 0x80000000,
    All = 0x0000001F,
    NoHeaps = 0x40000000
}

private struct MODULEENTRY32
{
    private const int MAX_PATH = 255;
    internal uint dwSize;   
    internal uint th32ModuleID;
    internal uint th32ProcessID;
    internal uint GlblcntUsage;
    internal uint ProccntUsage;
    internal IntPtr modBaseAddr;
    internal uint modBaseSize;
    internal IntPtr hModule;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 1)]
    internal string szModule;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH + 5)]
    internal string szExePath;
}

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot([In]UInt32 dwFlags, [In]UInt32 th32ProcessID);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle([In] IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Module32First(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref MODULEENTRY32 lpme);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Module32Next(IntPtr hSnapshot, ref MODULEENTRY32 lpme);

#endregion

static bool ProcessContainsModule(Process process, string searchTerm)
{
    bool result = false;

    //get handle to process
    IntPtr snapshotHandle = Environment.Is64BitProcess ?
        CreateToolhelp32Snapshot((UInt32)(SnapshotFlags.Module | SnapshotFlags.Module32), (UInt32)process.Id) :
        CreateToolhelp32Snapshot((UInt32)SnapshotFlags.Module, (UInt32)process.Id);
    if (snapshotHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return result;
    }

    //walk the module list
    try
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 entry = new MODULEENTRY32() { dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32)) };

        if (Module32First(snapshotHandle, ref entry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (entry.szModule.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }

                entry = new MODULEENTRY32() { dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32)) };
            }
            while (Module32Next(snapshotHandle, ref entry));
        }

        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseHandle(snapshotHandle);
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
static bool IsFlashLoadedInFirefox()
{
    return Process.GetProcessesByName("plugin-container").Any(x => ProcessContainsModule(x, "NPSWF"));
}

static bool IsFlashLoadedInInternetExplorer()
{
    //This doesn't work. For some reason can't get modules from child processes
    return Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore").Any(x => ProcessContainsModule(x, "Flash32"));
}

static bool IsFlashLoadedInChrome()
{
    //Doesn't work reliably. See description.
    return Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").Any(x => ProcessContainsModule(x, "pepflashplayer"));
}
```

As noted in the comments, only Firefox seems to work reliably. In the case of IE (IE11), `Module32First()` fails for some reason. In the case of Chrome, things get a bit more interesting:

- If a new tab is navigated to youtube.com or any YouTube video, the code works
- If a new tab is navigated to a play list on YouTube, however, the code fails because pepFlashPlayer.dll isn't in the module list of the process (checked with ProcessExplorer). What's more, if you continue to navigate to other non-playlist YouTube videos, it still doesn't show up.

Note that this approach of checking the loaded DLLs of a process is very fragile, and if any of the browsers decide to change either the DLL they load or how it is loaded then the code breaks.

**References:**

1. http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createtoolhelp32snapshot
2. http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/Module32First.html
3. http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/Module32Next.html